# How do I use Powershell to run vba program on an opened excel workbook

Tags: vba, excel, powershell, worksheet

I am building a powershell script to search for a specify opened excel workbook and run the vba on it.

It works well when there is one excel application with multiple workbooks.

However, it is not working when there are more than one excel application, since the code only search workbooks on one excel application. How do I search workbooks on all opened excel application?

Here is the code I am using

```
Try{
    # Check if any excel application is running
    $ExistingExcel = ((get-process excel | select MainWindowTitle, ID, StartTime | 
    Sort StartTime)).mainwindowtitle

    # Get existing excel application
    $excel = [Runtime.Interopservices.Marshal]::GetActiveObject('Excel.Application')

    # Get a list of workbook name in the excel application
    $ExcelList = $excel.workbooks | Foreach-object {$_.name}

    # Check if the list of workbooks contain the target workbook
    $targetWb = if ($ExcelList -contains "MyTargetWorkbook.xlsm") 
    {
         # Activate the target workbook and run the vba
         $excel.Workbooks.Item("MyTargetWorkbook.xlsm")
         $targetwb.Activate()
         $excel.run('MyVbaProgram')

    } else {
        # Do error handling
    }

}Catch{
    # Do error handling
}
```

Comment: `GetActiveObject` just returns the first instance it finds. You *might* be able to enumerate all of the open windows and attach to the processes with `AccessibleObjectFromWindow`, but COM doesn't really provide a general solution for what you're looking to do.

Comment: Can I attach the excel window using the process id?

Comment: Take a look at [this blog post](https://xldennis.wordpress.com/2007/11/25/access-running-instances-of-excel-in-vb/).

Comment: @Comintern Thanks for your comment. Now I decided to do all the tasks on powershell instead of using powershell to run vba program. I have used a powershell module called 'ImportExcel' to manipulate excel directly. The github for ImportExcel module : [ImportExcel](https://github.com/dfinke/ImportExcel)